# cakePHP 2.4 doesnt shows up on server

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.4

I'm new in cakePHP and I just finished my project so I wanted to upload it on server(hosting) but it doesnt run there. On local host(wamp) is everything okay.

CakePHP version 2.0 works on server perfect, but now Im using version 2.4 and it doesnt shows up even in initial condition as I downloaded it.

Does anyone know what to do please?
Thanks

Comment: Is it showing any error, message or its showing just blank page?

Comment: No error just blank site...

Comment: Did you check your webserver's log?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and what very strange.

Clear cache files (do not delete folders, just the files inside)

And I also experimented a problem with the ending of the files. Just delete any blank space after the last closing bracket of every model/controller file. I know this may sound awkward, but this solved my problem.